# PHP: problem inserting array inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, gchart

I have a script that is using the google charts API and the gChart wrapper.

I have an array that when dumped looks like this:

```
$values = implode(',', array_values($backup));
var_dump($values);
string(12) "8526,567,833"
```

I want to use the array like this:

```
$piChart = new gPieChart();
$piChart->addDataSet(array($values));
```

I would have thought this would have looked like this:

```
 $piChart->addDataSet(array(8526,567,833));
```

Howerver when I run the code it creates a chart with only the first value.

Now when I hardcode the values in instead I get each value in the chart.

Does anyone know why it's acting this way?

Jonesy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
$piChart->addDataSet(array_values($backup));
// or just: $piChart->addDataSet($backup); depends on $backup
```

should do it.

`$values` only contains a string. So if you do `array($values)`, you create an array with **one** element:

```
$values = "8526,567,833";
print_r(array($values));
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8526,567,833
)
```

`array(8526,567,833)` would be the same as `array_values($backup)` or maybe even just `$backup`, that depends on the `$backup` array.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to use `$backup` instead of `$values` as `$values` is the imploded string... and since `8526,567,833` isn't a valid number, it parses `8526` and leaves the rest alone.